# Filter a pandas dataframe based on a derived field

Tags: python, pandas, filter, dataframe, ipython

I have the below query that I execute and store in a pandas dataframe.

```
SELECT 
 mn as MachineName,
 dt as DateTime,
 REGEXP_EXTRACT(path, 'Name:([\\s\\S\\w\\W]*?)Domain:') AS Name1,
FROM TABLE DataGallery
```

Output of the query is:

```
MachineName  DateTime           Name1
GOG1         2016-12-13 12:14   PI1
GOG1         2016-12-14 13:12   PI2
```

I am trying to filter the dataframe based on df["Name1"] = "PI1". But this does not seem to work out. I tried the same for direct fields from table like "MachineName" and "DateTime", it works perfectly fine.

Not sure whether this filtering will not work for derived fields based on REGEXP_EXTRACT. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) if need filter `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name1': {0: 'PI1', 1: 'PI2'}, 
                   'DateTime': {0: '2016-12-13 12:14', 1: '2016-12-14 13:12'}, 
                   'MachineName': {0: 'GOG1', 1: 'GOG1'}}
                   ,columns=['MachineName','DateTime','Name1'])

print (df)
  MachineName          DateTime Name1
0        GOG1  2016-12-13 12:14   PI1
1        GOG1  2016-12-14 13:12   PI2

print (df.Name1 == 'PI1')
0     True
1    False
Name: Name1, dtype: bool

print (df[df.Name1 == 'PI1'])
  MachineName          DateTime Name1
0        GOG1  2016-12-13 12:14   PI1
```

Another solution with [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
print (df[df.Name1.str.contains('PI1')])

  MachineName          DateTime Name1
0        GOG1  2016-12-13 12:14   PI1
```

Comment: I tried all these options, it works for direct fields, but not for the derived fields. When i do it on empty fields, it throws an empty dataframe.

Comment: What does mean `derived fields` ? How can I simulate it?

Comment: The fields from REGEXP_EXTRACT, since these are not directly pulled from table, i manipulate the "path" from the table to get "Name1".

Comment: I also tried this: print (df[df.Name1 == '(.*)PI1(.*)']), even this does not work

Comment: I tthink you can use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) -  `print (df[df.Name1.str.contains('PI1')])`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Make sure its Capital "i" not Lowercase 'L".

```
  df[df["Name1"] == "PI1"] not df[df["Name1"] = "PI1"]
```